# HTML5 geolocation custom notification for user consent

Tags: html, geolocation

I am using HTML5 geolocation in my mobile web site. Just want to know is it possible that instead of  default notification of web browser for user consent to share location, I show custom notification and ask for the user consent through response to some button click event (much like when we install new application on mobile, a notification ask for our agreement to their terms and conditions ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the answer is no, you can't, this functionality must be implemented by the browsers rather than developers, as otherwise it could be used for accessing the camera without asking for someone's permission.